# Copy and add the html element in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Ques: I want to add the copy of label tag in result div each time when i press the submit button using Angularjs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name">
</label>

<div class="result">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="button button-positive">
Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea what do you want obtain by doing that, but please see example below that should helps you a bit.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.names = [
    
    {id:1}
  ];
  
  $scope.add = function(){
  
    var tmp =  $scope.names[0];
  
    
     $scope.names.push(tmp) 
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">

    <label class="item item-input" ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </label>

    <div class="result">
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="button button-positive" ng-click="add()">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Working fine as expected.